# How can I search for hotels with kitchen(ette)s?

Tags: hotels

How can I do so, without reading each hotel's website or contacting their staff? I prefer hotels belonging to [big hotel chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel#Further_reading), but not only extended-stay hotels.

Answer (score 5):

Same as when looking for a pet-friendly or breakfast-included hotel.

Use a search engine that offers that as a selection under amenities. You may have to click to an advanced page or something like that.

[image]

Comment: What search engine is your screenshot from?

Comment: Expedia, but there are others.